# get count of records inserted in each month

Tags: mysql

Get each months booking count and corresponding month name in given range of months.
suppose in the month of jan i added 5 records ,in feb 6 ,in march 8

i should get  the result in array with each months record count and corresponding month name

```
array("jan"=>5,"feb"=>6,"mar"=>8)
```

Comment: Please post your table schema and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I create table & insert values as

```
create table mytable (bookingID INT, myDate timestamp);

insert into mytable values
(1,'2012-02-21 12:12:12'),
(2,'2012-02-25 12:12:12'),
(3,'2012-02-24 12:12:12'),
(4,'2012-02-23 12:12:12'),
(5,'2012-02-22 12:12:12'),
(6,'2012-04-21 12:12:12'),
(7,'2012-03-21 12:12:12');
```

Then to get what you want, use below query

```
SELECT MONTH(myDate), COUNT(MONTH(myDate)) 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY MONTH(myDate);
```

If you want ***month name*** as **January**, use

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(myDate), COUNT(MONTH(myDate)) 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY MONTH(myDate);
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb50f/3)

Comment: I have one error ... `MONTHNAME' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT monthName, records FROM tableName WHERE month >= 1 AND month <= 12
```

This will select all months (1-12). monthName is the name of the months (assuming each row is a month, so 12 rows), records is the number of records in each row (each month), tableName is the name of your table, and month is an integer representation of the month (1-12)

Comment: do you think there would be month data other then 1-12? No need of WHERE condition...